# Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

Tags: google-compute-engine, gpu

I am trying to create the VM instance with NVIDIA K80 GPUs in Asia-East1 so, I requested to increase the quota and team have adjusted the quota. However, when I am trying to create the VM instance by selecting the NVIDIA K80 GPUs with 4 CPUs and Windows 2019 server, I am getting an error "Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally.". Please can you look into this issue and provide the solution.

Thanks & regards,
Tushar